# How to access EditText type in Android Studio?

Tags: android

How can I access an EditText type from Android Studio ? I have already done the UI Design before writing the code on the MainActivity file. Do I need an extra import file in order to access EditText Type?

All I have done was to type: EditText nameTxt.  But I got an error message at "EditText"

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple. Firstly, make sure that you have given your EditText an id in the Layout (UI) file. This is the line you would add.

```
android:id="@+id/layout_item_id"
```

Next go to your Java file and add this line in the onCreate() method.

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId)
```

Now if you want to get the text that is inside the EditText then you would add this line:

```
String string = myEditText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably yes, you are missing the import in your java file. Try adding the import

```
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Answer (score -1):

Type below Code for Java

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
```